# ESC key for back to main interface

Tags: c++, console, back

I have a problem with using the ESC key for back action. At the same time I want to receive user input too, but if the user wants to go back, they just press ESC key to go back. I tried to use while... getch(), but the problem is if I press backspace, the character that the user enters is not deleted.

Here is my code frame I made:

```
int main(){
  do{
    /* here I make my main interface */
    if (choice == "1"){
        /* here I wan to make [ESC] key for back to main interface
           Press only one time then back and the same time can input 
           data */
     }   
    ...

     else if (choice == "X" || choice == "x"){
       flag = false
      }

     else{
      wrongchoice();
     }
  }while(flag = true)
}
```

Comment: By the way, `case` doesn't work with "strings".  It works with single characters that use the single quote, such as 'x'.  Also, if you use `toupper` or `tolower` on the character before comparing, you only have to compare once.

Comment: Oh. My mistake, I already change it to if..else but that is not a main problem I got. Did you have any idea to design the ESC key?